# How to read Custom Property value and term description from NavigationTerm in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In publishing sharepoint 2013 site, I am using managed navigation. I need to read value of custom property defined in term store and I also need to read value of description field. Is it possible to do it with read access to site?

I can obtain TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm and read basic info. But to read custom property and description, I need to get taxonomy term and I cannot use read-only cached navigation term.

```
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
NavigationTerm navTerm = TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm;
Term term = navTerm.GetTaxonomyTerm(session); // I cannot do it due to permission level - user is read only user!
string val = term.CustomProperties["..."]; // this is what I need - read value of custom property - but without need to access Term class.
```

Is there a way how to read custom property from read-only navigation term with user assigned with read permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me for seo properties, if you debugging you can see the properties, you can get `CustomProperties` or `LocalCustomProperties` collection.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteGuid);
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
NavigationTerm navTermino = TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm;
Term termino = navTermino.GetTaxonomyTerm(session);

//var seoTitle = termino.CustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropBrowserTitle").SingleOrDefault();
var SEOPropBrowserTitle = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropBrowserTitle").SingleOrDefault();
var SEOPropDescription = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropDescription").SingleOrDefault();
var SEOPropKeyWords = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropKeywords").SingleOrDefault();
var SEOPropSiteNoIndex = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropSiteNoIndex").SingleOrDefault();
```